# How do I deal with new files when re-arranging commits in git

Tags: git

I have a file that is new and already in a commit.
After that I wanted to add a header to it, but put that commit before (Create the file with the header, then after add code).

What I have:

```
Commit A -> Create file with code
Commit B -> Add file header
```

What I want:

```
Commit A -> Create file with file header
Commit B -> Add code
```

Comment: Does "header" here just mean an extra set of lines at the top of the same file? Or does it mean a header file corresponding to a (source) code file?

Comment: Sorry, yes. File header, not header file.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to move your `HEAD` pointer to the parent of "Commit B" (using `reset`) and then selectively stage content for each commit.

Here are the general steps:

```
git reset CommitB^
git add path/to/newFile
git add -p
git commit -m 'first commit'

git add -p
git commit -m 'second commit'
```

`CommitB^` stands for the parent commit of "Commit B" (the `^` character is a way of referencing commit relatively). Replace `CommitB` with the SHA of "Commit B".

`git add -p` will ask y/n if you want to stage blocks of un-staged code. It is a useful tool to craft a commit with only a sub-set of the outstanding changes.